# How do I include and require a built-in node package in a React-Native app?

Tags: node.js, react-native, package, built-in

Node comes with some built-in packages, such as `crypto`. These are installed when Node is installed. They are not downloaded into the `node_packages` folder by `npm`.

How do I make one of these built-in packages available in my app so I can require it as follows:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
```

[Related unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070103/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-include-a-node-package-that-requires-crypto-module-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mvayngrib/react-native-crypto](https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-crypto) Node.js package does this.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't.

`crypto` isn't pollyfilled by react-native, see [issue 5049](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5049) for more info.

An alternative is to use a 3rd party module that attempts to mimic the crypto module in react-native but the few I checked were only partially implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stewart. Would a workaround be to webpack the module that relies on `crypto` and then require the packaged `.js` file?

Comment: Maybe a better way to ask this question is would a browser shim for `crypto` work with React-Native? https://mixmax.com/blog/requiring-node-builtins-with-webpack

Comment: I've found the polyfills that webpack uses (https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser) but after added `crypto-browserify` as a dependency in my root `package.json` I'm still seeing an `Unable to resolve 'crypto'` error in the simulator. How do I tell the React-Native packager to use the polyfill module?

Comment: I suspect you are going to struggle to solve this with this approach, maybe give https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js a try?

Comment: Thanks @Stewart, how do I get the RN packager to stop looking for `crypto` and use `crypto-js` instead? Is the only option to fork the offending library and change `require('crypto')` to `require('crypto-js')`?

Comment: I didn't realise that a library was using the `crypto` module and was under the impression that the app was referencing it directly. The answer you have posted may solve your problem but technically it is not using the `crypto` module but rather a port from `crypto-browserify` as well as not fully implemented. Glad you got it sorted though.